# My MediaPlayer and transition effect not working

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-transitions

Why I cannot put mp3 sound and transition effect to my button onClick?
While launching Activity2 my app crashing. How can I use MediaPlayer and my transition effect to my button onClick in private View.OnClickListener?

I'm using Transition effect (Bungee) from library

My code...

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button3;
private Button entrycity;

private static final String NAME = "name";
private boolean isEnabled;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(onButton1Click);
    entrycity = findViewById(R.id.entrycity);
    entrycity.setOnClickListener(onButton2Click);


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    isEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(winflagi.IS_ENABLED, false);
    entrycity.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    if (isEnabled){
        entrycity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval);

    }
    else {
        entrycity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval3);
    }
}
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menunewquite);
private View.OnClickListener onButton1Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, flagi1.class));
        mp.start();
       Bungee.fade(this);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener onButton2Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, cities1.class));
        mp.start
        Bungee.fade(this);
    }
};





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare MediaPlayer inside the body of the listener.